# PHP For Loop in code

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting my for loop to work in php. I am trying to make my code loop the time ten times with my css formating

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clockloop.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="bodycontainer">
        <h1> Clock Loop </h1><hr>
           <?php for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){

           <div id="border">
                <span id = "font">
                    <?php
                        echo date("G:i:s")
                    ?>
                </span>
            </div>
                <h3> Today is 
                    <?php 
                        echo date("F,j,Y")
                    ?>
                </h3>    

            } 
            ?>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The for loop is not working

Comment: It should be showing an error if the error reporting is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up your php tags opening and closing in the wrong places

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clockloop.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="bodycontainer">
        <h1> Clock Loop </h1><hr>
           <?php for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){?>

           <div id="border">
                <span id = "font">
                    <?php
                        echo date("G:i:s")
                    ?>
                </span>
            </div>
                <h3> Today is 
                    <?php 
                        echo date("F,j,Y")
                    ?>
                </h3>    
<?php
            } 
            ?>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONVERSELY** .. You said you wanted `10` times ..  This will output `11`, as 0 is still a quantifiable number ..

Comment: Very quick answer, good spotting.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just output HTML in PHP like that. You can echo or you can jump in and out like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clockloop.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="bodycontainer">
        <h1> Clock Loop </h1><hr>
           <?php for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){ ?><!-- note the closing PHP tag -->

           <div id="border">
                <span id = "font">
                    <?php
                        echo date("G:i:s")
                    ?>
                </span>
            </div>
                <h3> Today is 
                    <?php 
                        echo date("F,j,Y")
                    ?>
                </h3>    

            <?php } ?><!-- note the opening PHP tag -->    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want 10 repeats you should end your count at 9 because 0 will be your first record. You could also start with `$i = 1;` and use 10 as the count to number.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`this will reveal when you have errors in your syntax and alert you on where you should start debugging.

Comment: The error reporting information will be useful - if they take heed. +1.

Comment: One can always hope @Script47

Comment: Yet another amazing answer by Jay Blanana

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clockloop.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="bodycontainer">
    <h1> Clock Loop </h1><hr>
       <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){ ?>  => look at this line

       <div id="border">
            <span id = "font">
                <?php
                    echo date("G:i:s")
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
            <h3> Today is 
                <?php 
                    echo date("F,j,Y")
                ?>
            </h3>    
  <?php                                     => look at this line
        } 
        ?>    
</div>
```